# Discrete lines versus paths for interpolations

Tags: interpolation, d3.js

In the context describe in this article: [Path Transitions](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/path/), I am developing a tick chart from a data feed.

I like what Mike did in the path transitions example above, where he shows time axis transitions and interpolation of a running line using a path.

Instead of a path, I want to start with a simple simulated bar line to get the hang of D3. 
I think I can accomplish my tick chart application if someone can direct me on how to draw separate vertical bars for each new data input with transitions.

- Let's say the input is `Math.random()` (y1).
- Let's say we add `.2` to the height of each new pushed data point.
- We then do `.attr` of `x1,y1, x2,y2+.2` for each.

I don't know how to use *transform/translate* correctly.

I see the interpolations running Mike's code in the x-axis and I have created a `y-axis` the transitions as well. I am familiar with the topic but not competent enough to do this simple line bar version.